# For all integers $m$ there exists a map $f: S^{1} \to S^{1}$ with degree $m$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-homomorphism

I know intuitively how to construct the map in question, namely by $f(e^{i\theta})=e^{im\theta}$. But I'm having trouble with proving that $\deg(f)=m$. You could prove it by showing that the chains $m\cdot\phi\:$ and $f\circ\phi\:$ are homologous if you take $\phi + B_1(S^{1})$ to be a generator of $H_1(S^{1})$. But how do  I do this? This would be a rather direct proof but are there some other theorems that would prove it indirectly?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re okay with computing degree as a sum of local degrees, then note that if you take any point in the image, it has $m$ points in the preimage. At each of these points, $f$ is orientation-preserving so all the local degrees are 1 so you get $deg(f) = \sum_{i=1}^m 1 = m$.

Alternatively, if you know explicit generators of $H_1(S^1)$, you can consider the effect of $f$ on it. In particular, if you take the CW-structure of $S^1$ to be two 0-cells and two 1-cells, denoting the 1-cells by $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ as Hatcher does, then you can easily see that $deg(f) = f_\ast(\Delta_1 - \Delta_2) = m(\Delta_1 - \Delta_2)$ so the degree is $m$.

There are many other ways of showing this, so depending on what your background is, we could provide suitable answers!

Comment: I would be interested in a proof using arguments from homological algebra since the exercise is from a book on Homology Theory. Regarding your answer: f isn't orientation preserving if m<0 for example. But you could just assume that m is positiva and take the composition of f with the antipodal map to create a map with degree -m.

Comment: Nevermind, [this](https://gyazo.com/3ab80b0176c36d0f392cf89761b1f695) lemma completed the proof.